# Invoking userEvent click in test script showing navigate() error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am pulling some data from backend (nock mock calls) and storing it in an array. Then I am looping over the data and wrapping each array item with an `<a href="/test">` link. Clicking on the link will take us to the detail page.

I am testing above functionality in react testing library. In the test file I am calling `render(<App/>)` . Then I am searching the data returned from backend for a particular item.

I can see that the backend data is retrieved correctly from backend as `screen.debug(elem)` is showing the matched element in the log.

Then I invoke click  using `userEvent.click` on the matched item (which is wrapped inside the link `<a href="/test">`). This click is supposed to take us to the detail page. It is at this point an error shows

```
  console.warn
    You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.

      265 |         //screen.debug(elem);
      266 |
    > 267 |         await userEvent.click(elem);
          |                         ^
      268 |         screen.debug();
      269 |
      270 |

      at Object.warning (node_modules/@remix-run/router/utils.ts:791:49)
      at navigate (node_modules/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx:180:7)
      at internalOnClick (node_modules/react-router-dom/index.tsx:727:9)
      at handleClick (node_modules/react-router-dom/index.tsx:385:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
      at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
      at executeDispatch (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
      at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
      at processDispatchQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
      at dispatchEventsForPlugins (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9097:3)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9288:12
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26140:12)
      at batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3991:12)
      at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:9287:3)
      at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6465:5)
      at dispatchEvent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6457:5)
      at dispatchDiscreteEvent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6430:5)
      at HTMLDivElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLAnchorElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLAnchorElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:25:20
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:79:16
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:64:24
      at act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2512:16)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:63:25
      at Object.eventWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:78:28)
      at fireEvent (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:16:35)
      at Function.fireEvent.<computed> [as click] (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:125:36)
      at fireClick (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:150:20)
      at clickElement (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:91:5)
      at Object.click (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:140:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:267:25)

  console.log
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="products-container"
        >
          <div
            class="products-list"
          >
            <a
              href="/test"
            >
              <div
                class="product"
              >
                <div
                  class="product-title"
                >
                  Samsung Note 10 Lite | 10% Price Drop
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a
              href="/test"
            >
              <div
                class="product"
              >
                <div
                  class="product-title"
                >
                  Samsung Galaxy S21 Plus 5G (Phantom Black, 8GB RAM, 128GB Storage)
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

If instead of using dynamic data from backend if I just use some static data as return output from the component, then the test works correctly.

```
test('renders learn react link', async () => {
    
        //nock mock requests for backend calls
        
        render(<App/>);

        let elem;
                
        await waitFor(() => {            
            elem = screen.getByText("Product Label 1").parentElement.parentElement;
            expect(elem).toBeInTheDocument;            
        });
        screen.debug(elem);
          
        await userEvent.click(elem);
        screen.debug();       

        await waitFor(async () => {
            let elem2 = await screen.findByText("Lorem Ipsum");
        });


    });
```

This is the file retrieving the backend data

```
const ProductsList = () => {
    const [productsList, setProductsList] = useState([]);
    const [noDataFound, setNoDataFound] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([]);
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [mongoDB, setMongoDB] = useState(null);  
    
    const context = React.useContext(AppContext);
    const userContext = React.useContext(UserContext);   
    
    const app = context.app;
    const user = userContext.user;  

    useEffect(() => {
        
        const getDatabase = async () => {            
            let database = await user?.mongoClient("atlas");            
            setMongoDB( database );         
        }
        
        user && getDatabase();
        
    }, [user]);

    useEffect(() => {      
        const getProducts = async () => {

            console.log("calling realm");
            const col =  mongoDB.db("dbname").collection("collectionname");
            
            const products =  await col.aggregate(
                [
                    {"$skip" : 0 },
                    {"$limit": 12 }
                ]);
            if(!products || products.length === 0 ){
                setNoDataFound(true);
            }else{
                setNoDataFound(false);
            }
            
            setProductsList(products);
            
        }
        
        mongoDB && getProducts();
        
    }, [searchData, mongoDB, searchParams]);

    useEffect(() => {       
        
        if(productsList || productsList?.length === 0)
            setIsLoading(false);
        
    }, [productsList, setProductsList]);

    const getProducts = () => {

        return productsList.map( product => {           
           
            return (
                <Link to="/test" key={product['product-title']}>
                    <div className="product">                                       
                        <div className="product-title">{product['product-title']}</div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            )
            
        });
    }

    return (
        <>              
            {                
                    <div className="products-container">    
                        <div className="products-list">
                            {productsList && productsList.length > 0 && getProducts()}
                        </div>
                    </div> 
            }            
        </>
    );
    
}
```

This is the Parent App

```
function App() {
  return <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<ProductsList />} /> 
                <Route exact path="/test" element={<ProductDetail />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
}
```

This is file that is navigated to when userEvent.click is invoked

```
const ProductDetail = () => {
    return <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It seems like rendering `<Link>` dynamically causes problems. In my case the test fails somewhat randomly, something like 1 out of 3 times. I see that the Link component uses a couple of hooks under the hood, so maybe that's the cause of it.

My solution was to change `<Link>` to a normal anchor tag and programatically navigate in its onClick handler, something along the lines of:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';


function ItemList() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const items = [ /* your items */ ];

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          <a href="#" onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigate('/foo/' + item.id);
          }}>
            {item.name}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```